# How can I add a list of Matrices in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have already built a function that adds two matrices, now I'm trying to reuse the same function and make up for a function that sums up a LIST of matrices.

I keep getting errors and out of range indexes..

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks a lot!

This is what I have done:

```
def add_matrices(a, b):
answer = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        row.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
    answer[i].append(row)
return answer


print(add_matrices([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16]]))
print(add_matrices([[1,-2],[-4,5]],[[3,2],[5,-4]]))

def sum_matrices(mat_lst):
answer = []
for i in range(1, len(mat_lst)):
    row = []
    for j in range(1, len(a[0][0])):
        row.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
    answer.append(row)
return answer

print(sum_matrices([[[1,-2],[-4,5]],[[3,2],[5,-4]]]))
print(sum_matrices([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16]],[[21,22,23],[24,25,26]],[[31,32,13],[34,35,36]]]))
```

Comment: This code has several issues: you are using a and b in `for i in range(1, len(mat_lst)):` for example. Moreover, `i` is for the list of matrices and `j` is for the number of columns in some matrix, and so, on...

Answer (score 1):

numpy has implemented much of what you are already trying to do. And it will scale much better.

Matrix Addition Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> x2 = np.array([[11,12,13],[14,15,16]])
>>> result = x1 + x2
>>> result
array([[12, 14, 16],
       [18, 20, 22]])
```

If you want to sum up a list of matrices it is as simple as:

```
>>> x = [x1, x2]
>>> sum(x)
array([[12, 14, 16],
       [18, 20, 22]])
```

And if you want it specifically as a python nested list:

```
>>> sum(x).tolist()
[[12, 14, 16], [18, 20, 22]]
```

Hope this helps!